# Error connecting to Azure Virtual Network - Point to Site

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I followed this tutorial to create a point-to-site connection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Now, when i try to connect the VPN I get this error:

`A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol. (Error 798)`

[image]

It doesn't even work in the computer that I generated the self-signed cert. Neither it works in another client that I installed the pfx private key and fails in both with the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out the document to create the certs are not complete here and not mentioning anything about the client cert and it just says how to create a root cert:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site

Here is what I had to do to make it work:

Create root cert:

```
makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=AzureRootCert" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "AzureRootCert.cer"
```

Create client cert:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=AzureClientCert" -pe -sky exchange -m 96 -ss My -in "AzureRootCert" -is my -a sha1
```

Then the rest is documented. so have to export the root cert and upload to Azure and then download the VPN tool.